# jquery tabs and telerik and ajax datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, tabs, datepicker

I am using jquery UI tabs and adding a telerik datepicker to it(dont want to use jquery datepicker for styling issues)..I can see the control on the tab but when i click it, it doesn't open and the url changes to `http://localhost/#`.

I have tried ajax CalendarExtender and same thing happens.

I dont get any errors as such.

I am using jquery 1.5.1 and jquery-ui-1.8.11.js.

edit ::

on master page i have :

```
    <link href="Content/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/cufon/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/cufon/Lubalin_Graph_700.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.watermark.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and my tab structure is :

```
        <div id="tabs">
                <ul>
                    <li title=""><a href="FAQs.aspx">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li title=""><a href="Profile.aspx">Profile</a></li>
                    <li title=""><a href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
        </div>
```

and jquery is:

```
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $(ui.panel).empty();
            $(ui.panel).append("preloader.gif' />");
        },
        cache: false,
        ajaxOptions: { cache: false }
    });
```

in profile aspx page i have this ajax:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
                        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
                        </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

and for telerik:

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker runat="server" ID="date" Width="110px" ></telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

Comment: make sure there are no errors on the console. check console window for errors

Comment: @ravi i have and i cannot see any errors

Comment: are tabs being ajax loaded?

Comment: @charlietfl yes they are

Comment: please show code then, can't initialize your datepicker before element exists but can use the tabs load event to do it

Comment: each tab has an aspx page n if i navigate to that page i can see it working fine but not in tab...which part of code do you want to see

Comment: show basic structure of remote page, script order likely needs to be changed since `document.ready` has already occured on main page

Comment: @charlietfl see my edit above please, the datepicker controls are in profile page

Comment: you posted structure for main page not remote page, read my answer and should help

Comment: by remote page do you mean the profile page, if so it is just html markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When AJAX loading a page is important to understand that all load events have already occurred on the main page. This means that any code wrapped in load handlers or `document.ready` on remote page will fire as soon as they are loaded and won't wiat for any subsequent html to load first

If the scripts in remote page exist prior to the html they refer to they will fire before that html exists.

Placing the html before the script will remedy this.

Alternatively you can use the tabs load event to make a `$.getScript` call

EDIT: Following code is from jQueryUI tabs API and will fire every time a tab is ajax loaded:

```
$( "#tabs" ).on( "tabsload", function( event, ui ) {
   var active = $(this).tabs('option','active');
    /* index starts at zero for first tab*/
   if(active==2){
     /* iniitalize datepicker here*/
   }

});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but how do I place the html before the script as script is in master page

Comment: see my edit please. it is in profile that i have ajax and telerik calendar extender / datepicker

Comment: I don't do much in asp, and know nothing about telurik. If standalone page autoinitializes the dateepicker based on your asp code, it will not do same in AJAX load and you will have to call that code yourself

Comment: find the code needed to initialize the datepicker manually, or link to API for it. I will give you some tab load event code you can use it in